# why A Soldier’s Play by Fuller has "play" in its title

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

is there a soldier playing in the story?
is there a play enacted by the soldier?
or is tehre any soldier that plays a trick on someone?]

what justify the word "Play" A soldier'play title?

Comment: Have you watched, listened to, or read the play? That's the *first* bit of "background research" you should do before asking us about it. Note that a ***play*** has a wide range of possible meanings. The reference might be akin to ***a "play" in football*** (a pre-planned series of coordinated moves intended to achieve a goal). Perhaps it's about one or more soldiers implementing some planned action. Or perhaps it's just a play that Fuller thinks soldiers would be interested in. But that's all Off Topic Lit Crit, not something "fixed" by the particular words used in the title.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the author's intention, but the simplest explanation of the title is that it is just descriptive of the work itself: This is a play (a staged drama) about a soldier. Note that when a movie was made from this play, the title was changed to "A Soldier's Story" -- and the play's author, Charles Fuller, had written the movie screenplay.

This being fiction and literature, it's entirely possible that the author was using the word "play" in the sense of *tactic*, *plan*, *drama*, or any other of the word's colloquial meanings or connotations.